# JDBC delete statement with multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

It says I ended this statement wrong when if I input it into sql plus with just the addition of ; it works perfectly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("delete from aplbuk  MODEL = '"+   textField_4.getText()  + "'AND  year = '" + textField_1.getText()  + "' AND Litres = '" + textField_2.getText() 
    + "' AND ENGINE_TYPE = '" + textField_3.getText() + "'");
    statement.close();
```

Comment: *"when if I input it into sql plus with just the addition of ; it works perfectly."*  I doubt that that is true!  You've left out a mandatory keyword, and SQLPLUS would have rejected that.

Comment: Please use prepared statements with a parameterized query to protect yourself against SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

Keyword `where` is missing after table name `aplbuk` in your query `delete from aplbuk MODEL`.

Update the query as:

```
  statement.executeUpdate("delete from aplbuk  where  MODEL = '"+   
                           textField_4.getText()  + "'AND  year = '" + 
                           textField_1.getText()  + "' AND Litres = '" + 
                           textField_2.getText() + "' AND ENGINE_TYPE = '" + 
                           textField_3.getText() + "'");
```

Also if `year` and `Litres` are numeric fields then don't enclose the value in single quotes.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I left it out, all the other statements had it on it and were the same. Thanks

Comment: @user1643033 If this is helpful then don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the arrow sign next to to the vote counts in the front of the answer.